# How to run a project checked out from git android

Tags: android, gradle, build

I was running my android project on windows but now i have installed studio on linux.I checked out my project from git and now trying to run it on my studio in linux.The gradle build is running but noting is happening I dont know how to solve this.I think it is the problem with the version. Maybe the studio on my windows have a different version and linux have different.How to run this project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a project, you have just open it with Android Studio, wait for indexing, and start it with the play button on a virtual device or on a real device